# a class design problem

Tags: c++, class

In the book of "The C++ programming language", author gave the following example. He mentioned that " the cache needs to be filled before it can be used". It seems to me that this is why the function of compute_cache_value is placed. But I do not understand what does the function of string_rep( ) do in accordance with its implementation. Thanks for clarification.

```
class Date{
      bool cache_valid;
      string cache;
      void compute_cache_value( );  //fill cache
      // ...
public: 
      // ...
     string string_rep( ) const;
};

string Date:: string_rep( ) const
{
    if (cache_valid == false) {
          Date* th = const_cast<Date*> (this); // cast away const
          th->compute_cache_value( );
          th->cache_valid = true;
    }
    return cache;
}
```

In addition, the author gave the following for examples:

```
Date d1;
const Date d2;
string s1 = d1.string_rep( );
string s2 = d2.string_rep( );
```

And the author stated that the fourth example will display undefined behavior. I would like to know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string_rep` checks to see if there's a cached string representation of the date. If not, it calls the `compute_cache_value` method to create the string representation and cache it, and then marks the cache representation as valid so future calls to `string_rep` don't recalculate it.

The line `const Date d2;` will display undefined behavior because the compiler may assume it can put `d2` in nonvolatile memory (e.g. flash in a microcontroller, or read-only-flagged memory or memory-mapped memory), and the `const_cast<Date*>` may not work in that case, resulting in `cache_valid` staying `false` or `cache` staying as an empty string.

P.S. As Michael J below points out below, there are almost always better ways to do things than using `const_cast`.  In the case of this example, the `mutable` keyword comes in handy. In short, marking a class member `mutable` tells the compiler that the member may be changed even if the object is `const`.

```
class Date
{
      mutable bool cache_valid;
      mutable string cache;
      void compute_cache_value() const;
      // ...
public: 
      // ...
     string string_rep() const;
};

string Date::string_rep() const
{
    if (cache_valid == false) {
          compute_cache_value();
          cache_valid = true;
    }
    return cache;
}
```

... though I'd argue that it's `compute_cache_value`'s responsibility to set `cache_valid`, and I'd consider adding `operator string() const { return string_rep(); }` to `Date`.

One last thing that's neat about `mutable` is that the compiler has a better idea of what is going on, and in a case like `d2`, can put the object in volatile memory despite its declaration as `const`.

Answer (score 1):

string_rep() returns a string representation of the cache data.  The undefined behavior in example 4 comes about because of the explicit declaration of d2 as const.  const_cast can only be used (with defined behavior) to cast away implicit const'ness.

Answer (score 0):

In some conditions, a data member that ought to be mutable, a compiler that doesn't support the mutable keyword, and an object that was originally defined to be const, the Standard says the behavior is undefined.
The compiler is indeed allowed to put the object in a read-only memory as an optimization.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.13
http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/017.htm

Answer (score 0):

The function string_rep is marked as "const".  That is telling the compiler that it will not modify the object.  However, by playing clever tricks with const_cast(), it does actually change the object.

This is dangerous in every case as the compiler may perform some optimisation that assumes the object is not modified and this may lead to all sorts of problems, including possible data corruption.

This is doubly bad in the case of d2 as d2 is a const object.  It might be stored in memory that is marked "read-only".

So what will happen?

1. Mostly nothing.  It will probably just work.
2. Sometimes it will silently fail to update the memory and the cache will contain garbage.
3. Possibly it will cause an exception and crash the program.
4. It *might* trick the optimiser into doing something crazy and then all bets are off.  At that point, almost anything could happen.

Bottom line: it is unnecessary and stupid.  Don't do it.  There are almost always better ways than casting away const-ness.